# Run WPF application with Powershell during logon

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I have a powershell script and want to force running, after user successfully logon on the windows 7 machine.
Powershell script looks as follow:

```
$job = Start-Job { Start-Process -FilePath \\company\path\Comparer\Comparer.exe -PassThru -Wait -WindowStyle Normal }
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job

$programName = 'Comparer'
$isRunning = (Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $programName }).Count -gt 0

while($isRunning) {

    $isRunning = (Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $programName }).Count -gt 0
}
```

What the script is doing, it will start running programm comparer and it will keep running until comparer finished they process.
I assigned the script on logon:[image]
and the comparer programm does not start at all during logon.

After I've try to assign the powershell to logoff also **and it works**.
Why it does not work on logon?